# asio async operations aren't processed

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am following ASIO's  [async_tcp_echo_server.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)  example to write a server.

My server logic looks like this (.cpp part):

1.Server startup:

```
bool Server::Start()
{
  mServerThread = std::thread(&Server::ServerThreadFunc, this, std::ref(ios));
  //ios is asio::io_service
}
```

2.Init acceptor and listen for incoming connection:

```
void Server::ServerThreadFunc(io_service& service)
{
    tcp::endpoint endp{ address::from_string(LOCAL_HOST),MY_PORT };
    mAcceptor = acceptor_ptr(new tcp::acceptor{ service,endp });
    // Add a job to start accepting connections.
    StartAccept(*mAcceptor);
    // Process event loop.Hang here till service terminated
    service.run();
    std::cout << "Server thread exiting." << std::endl;
}
```

3.Accept a connection and start reading from the client:

```
void Server::StartAccept(tcp::acceptor& acceptor)
{

    acceptor.async_accept([&](std::error_code err, tcp::socket socket)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            std::make_shared<Connection>(std::move(socket))->StartRead(mCounter);
            StartAccept(acceptor);

        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Error:" << "Failed to accept new connection" << err.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    });

}

void Connection::StartRead(uint32_t frameIndex)
{
    asio::async_read(mSocket, asio::buffer(&mHeader, sizeof(XHeader)), std::bind(&Connection::ReadHandler, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, frameIndex));
}
```

So the Connection instance finally triggers `ReadHandler` callback where I perform actual read and write:

```
 void Connection::ReadHandler(const asio::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transfered, uint32_t frameIndex)
{

   if (bytes_transfered == sizeof(XHeader)) 
    {

            uint32_t reply;
            if (mHeader.code == 12345) 
            {
                reply = (uint32_t)12121;
                size_t len = asio::write(mSocket, asio::buffer(&reply, sizeof(uint32_t)));
            }
            else
            {
                reply = (uint32_t)0;
                size_t len = asio::write(mSocket, asio::buffer(&reply, sizeof(uint32_t)));
                this->mSocket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
                return;
            }
    }

    while (mSocket.is_open())
    {
        XPacket packet;
        packet.dataSize = rt->buff.size();
        packet.data = rt->buff.data();
        std::vector<asio::const_buffer> buffers;
        buffers.push_back(asio::buffer(&packet.dataSize,sizeof(uint64_t)));
        buffers.push_back(asio::buffer(packet.data, packet.dataSize));

        auto self(shared_from_this());
        asio::async_write(mSocket, buffers,
            [this, self](const asio::error_code error, size_t bytes_transfered)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                     ERROR(200, "Error sending packet");
                     ERROR(200, error.message().c_str());
                }
            }
        );

    }


}
```

Now, here is the problem. The server receives data from the client and sends ,using sync `asio::write`, fine. But when it comes to to `asio::async_read` or `asio::async_write` inside the while loop, the method's lambda callback never gets triggered, unless I put `io_context().run_one();` immediately after that. I don't understand why I see this behaviour. I do call `io_service.run()` right after acceptor init, so it blocks there till the server exit. The only difference of my code from the asio example, as far as I can tell, is that I run my logic from a custom thread.

Comment: The thread is running `Connection::ReadHandler`, which isn't returning. When/where do you expect the callback to be called?

Comment: @Hasturkun Look at StartRead() method, the ReadHandler is the callback to the first async_read. Also, Connection::ReadHandler doesn't return untill the server is shut down from the main thread or any error occurs inside its while loop. Is that is what prevents service.run() to execute?

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear. Your server thread (running the event loop) has called into the `ReadHandler` function, which won't return so long as `mSocket.is_open()` is true. Since that function doesn't return, the event loop won't run. If it did return, the lambda would get called.

Comment: Oh, now I got you. Sounds logical. Now, what are my options in this case?I do need those writes/reads to be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback isn't returning, preventing the event loop from executing other handlers.

In general, if you want an asynchronous flow, you would chain callbacks e.g. callback checks `is_open()`, and if true calls `async_write()` with itself as the callback.

In either case, the callback returns.

This allows the event loop to run, calling your callback, and so on.

In short, you should make sure your asynchronous callbacks always return in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: I got you, but in my case I do need to run in a while() loop. Is calling service,run_one() acceptable workaround in this scenario?Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelIvanov: You can effectively replace your while() loop with a chain of callbacks. I'll try to add an example shortly, but a while loop and a callback that is called repeatedly (with a condition test) are mostly equivalent. Calling `service.run_one()` technically makes this complete synchronously.

Comment: Yes, I see. My only concern in this respect is that because the while loop does some work very fast, I am afraid of performance aspect related to a large amount of async handlers spawn.

Comment: There should be no problem with a loop so long as it does a finite amount of work. It could work in batches for instance. I should probably note that at some point the socket will not be writable, so any async_write you perform from that point would need a running event loop to work.